# Recursive Sudoku Solver Incorrect solution (C++)

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking

I am trying to implement a recursive backtracking solution to a soduko board however, I am getting a board with an incorrect solution. I am not sure why it's the case when my recurrence is correct:

```
bool solveSudoku(vector< vector<char> >& board) {
    for (int i=0; i<9; ++i){
        for (int j=0; j<9; ++j){
            if (board[i][j]=='.'){
                for (int k=0; k<9; ++k){
                    board[i][j]=('1'+k);
                    if (check(i,j, board) && solveSudoku(board)){
                            return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
bool check(int i, int j, vector< vector<char> >& board){
    //check horizontal
    for (int l=0; l<9; ++l){
        if (board[i][l]==board[i][j] && l!=j){
            return false;
        }
    }
    //check vertical
    for (int l=0; l<9; ++l){
        if (board[l][j]==board[i][j] && l!=i){
            return false;
        }
    }
    //check block
    int block_x = i/3;
    int block_y = j/3;
    block_x*=3;
    block_y*=3;
    for(int l=0; l<3; ++l){
        for (int k=0; k<3; ++k){
            if (board[block_x+l][block_y+k]==board[i][j] && block_x+l!=i && block_y+k!=j){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    //all valid so return true
    return true;
}
```

Comment: My first guess is that your code does not works because you don't make a copy and thus you don't fully restore the state on backtracking.

Comment: @Phil1970 I am passing the board by reference so all the recursion is working on the same board so it is keeping the previous states

Comment: My advice is to roll back to the original question and self answer it.

Comment: @drescherjm Done. Rolled the question back and Answered.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up Figuring it out. I just needed to add board[i][j]='.' before the return false! Here is the full code:

```
bool solveSudoku(vector< vector<char> >& board) {
    for (int i=0; i<9; ++i){
        for (int j=0; j<9; ++j){
            if (board[i][j]=='.'){
                for (int k=0; k<9; ++k){
                    board[i][j]=('1'+k);
                    if (check(i,j, board) && solveSudoku(board)){
                            return true;
                    }
                }
                board[i][j]='.';
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
bool check(int i, int j, vector< vector<char> >& board){
    //check horizontal
    for (int l=0; l<9; ++l){
        if (board[i][l]==board[i][j] && l!=j){
            return false;
        }
    }
    //check vertical
    for (int l=0; l<9; ++l){
        if (board[l][j]==board[i][j] && l!=i){
            return false;
        }
    }
    //check block
    int block_x = i/3;
    int block_y = j/3;
    block_x*=3;
    block_y*=3;
    for(int l=0; l<3; ++l){
        for (int k=0; k<3; ++k){
            if (board[block_x+l][block_y+k]==board[i][j] && block_x+l!=i && block_y+k!=j){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    //all valid so return true
    return true;
}
```